# How to use ip start & ip end to find out location

Tags: php, ip

```
type    ip_start    ip_end          country     state       city

ipv4    0.0.0.0     0255.255.255    US          California  Los Angeles
ipv4    1.0.0.0     1.0.0.255       AU          Queensland  Brisbane
```

I have a table contain ip list for country, state and city.

My question is how can I detect user's ip location from my db

If I use php `$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]; , HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR & REMOTE_ADDR` to find out user's ip.

**How can I use this variable to find out which country, state & city from my db?**

**How ip_start & ip_end work?**

ex. if my ip is  `$ip=123.243.51.83;`

How can I use this $ip to find out location from my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP addresses can be converted to numbers. You can use this to find out which range the ip is in.

Using MySQL and `INET_ATON`:

```
SELECT country FROM table WHERE 
INET_ATON("123.243.51.83") BETWEEN INET_ATON(ip_start) AND INET_ATON(ip_end);
```

Using PHP and `ip2long`:

```
$yourIpLong = ip2long($yourIp);
if($yourIpLong > ip2long($ipStart) && $yourIpLong < ip2long($ipEnd)){
     //IP is in range $ipStart -> $ipEnd
}else{
    //IP is not in range.
}
```

Note that both these solutions are for IPv4.

Comment: so ip start & ip end is the range? ex. start-1 end-5 than 4 will be in this range 6 will not?

Comment: @BenWong Correct, in your example 123.243.51.83 converts to a number that is between, say 125.0.0.0 and 100.0.0.0

Comment: why 125.0.0.0-100.0.0.0? why not 124.0.0.0-125.0.0.0?

Comment: Sorry that should be 100.0.0.0 and 125.0.0.0 It's also between  124.0.0.0 and 125.0.0.0 (and between 123.243.51.82 and 123.243.51.84)

Comment: at morment i store ipv4 & ipv6 int(10) together and I try to convert this column to ip_start_long

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you store the IP addresses in an integer representation. You can use the MySql function [INET_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) for that.

In PHP you can calculate it with:

```
$address = '174.36.207.186';

$addressArray = explode('.', $address);

$integerIp =   ( 16777216 * $addressArray[0] )
             + (    65536 * $addressArray[1] )
             + (      256 * $addressArray[2] )
             +              $addressArray[3];
```

The query (if you have stored it as integer in DB ) would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
".$integerIp." BETWEEN ip_start AND ip_end
LIMIT 1
```

You also can do the coversion directly in the DB like Jim answered but why let the DB do the calculation if you can precompute it?

Comment: so i have to conversion all ip_start & ip_end in my db?

Comment: yes I would recommend to make 2 new integer fields `ip_start_num` and `ip_end_num` and update the table with `UPDATE table SET ip_start_num = INET_ATON(ip_start), ip_end_num = INET_ATON(ip_end)`

Comment: my db has more than 3 million rows, lol, i think it will take me 3 or 4 day to update

Comment: this is exactly the reason why I would precompute it. you only have to run the update once.

Comment: let me do the query first to see how fast it goes and I may update later